# Sort Table by distance (latitude and longitude)

Tags: ios, sorting, location, tableview, distance

I'm getting values by JSON like that:

```
{
        id = 1;
        latitude = "-23.0002";
        longitude = "-43.2438";
        name = Vips;
}

{
        id = 2;
        latitude = "-22.9283";
        longitude = "-43.1746";
        name = Elegance;
}
```

...

I need to show this values in a tableview, sort by distance to the user location. And have to update always this value. How can I do this?

displayObject is a NSMutableArray that I'm taking the values from WS.
In viewWillappear I'm trying to do:

```
NSArray *rawData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:displayObject];

rawData = [rawData sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {

    CLLocationDistance dist_a= [[a objectForKey:@"coordinate"] distanceFromLocation: locAtual];
    CLLocationDistance dist_b= [[b objectForKey:@"coordinate"] distanceFromLocation: locAtual];
    if ( dist_a < dist_b ) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if ( dist_a > dist_b) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

But it's not working. I just have, latitude and longitude. I dont have the "coordinate".
Someone??

thank you!!

Comment: Do you need to save the distance along with the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are calculating the distance, add it along with the data stored in array and then sort based the distance.

```
for (int idx = 0; idx<[displayObject count];idx++) {

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [displayObject[idx] mutableCopy];
    CLLocationDegrees latitude = [dict[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = [dict[@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
    //Storing as string since latitude and longitude is also string values
    //Since its a dictionary storing as NSNumber is better
    dict[@"distance"] = [@(distance) stringValue];

    displayObject[idx] = dict;

}

//sorting based on distance
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
[displayObject sortUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you very much!!
And you know how can I update the table when user moves?
Thank you!!

Comment: I know that in didUpdateToLocation I can use [self.tableView reloadData];
But I don't have sure that is gonna work, and how can I sort again if I need it?

Comment: @FabioSilva You need to recalculate the distance when the userLocation  changes, sort the array . Then reload the tableView.

Comment: I tried to do that in didUpdateToLocation I call [self updateTableViewLocations]; that does this function that you told me.

But even in simulator, the updateTableViewLocations don't stop to repeat. Keep doing a lot of times. And my position stay the same. I'm in simulator!

Answer (score 1):

First create locations objects with latitude and longitude:

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-23.0002 longitude:-43.2438];
CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-23.0002 longitude:-43.2438];
```

With those 2 objects, it's easy to check the distance using:

```
 -(CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

For example:

```
CLLocationDistance dist_a = [locationUser distanceFromLocation:location];
```

Comment: Thanks!!

I put this in a loop to get all values.

CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
CLLocationDistance dist_a = [location distanceFromLocation:locAtual];
NSString *lc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dist_a];
[sortDistance addObject:lc];

Now I have an array with the distances, and I have to sort it? It's something in this way?

Comment: Just use this: array = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)]; if the values are numbers

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand! The things I did it, I dont need?

Comment: if you use numbers, you don't need to implement the compare method, just use what I wrote

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator was wrong. Try this instead:

```
rawData = [rawData sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) 
{
    CLLocation *locationA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[a objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[a objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]];
    CLLocation *locationB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[b objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[b objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]];

    CLLocationDistance dist_a = [locationA distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
    CLLocationDistance dist_b = [locationB distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

    if ( dist_a < dist_b ) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( dist_a > dist_b) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```